# What is the Fastest way to reorder an array

Tags: java, arrays

What is the fastest (realtime data processing application) way to reorder (the new indices are always the same) an array in JAVA:

e.g.:
I have got:
    `double[] A = new double[] {1, 234, 12,99,0};`

I need to get swiftly:
    `double[] B =  new double[] {A[2], A[4], A[0],A[1],A[3]};`

But maybe this is this is the most efficient way to do it anyway?

many thanks for your feedback

Comment: Is your current approach too slow?

Comment: You can remove `new double[]` in both places, but I don't see how you expect to do any better than this, or why you think it might be a code bottleneck, or, if you don't, why you care at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do better than your current approach of

```
double[] B = new double[] {A[2], A[4], A[0], A[1], A[3]};
```

Likely candidates for other sequences might be forms of `Arrays.copyOf` or `Arrays.copyOfRange`, but the minimum amount of work you must do here consists of:

- create a new array
- random access to each element in the array

There's a small chance that you might do slightly better with very specific read/write orders (to take advantage of cache lines), one guess is something that reads entirely in order and writes almost entire in ascending order:

```
   double[] B = new double[A.length];
   B[2] = A[0];
   B[3] = A[1];
   B[4] = A[3];
   B[0] = A[2];
   B[1] = A[4];
```

But I don't have strong expectations of this being noticeably better. If you're at the point where you're trying to eliminate or optimize on L1/L2 cache hits, it's time to start micro-benchmarking, and the real answer is you should experiment.