# Fastest way to move simple data types in array to specific positions

Tags: c++, c, arrays, performance

What is the fastest way to move simple data types in array of known size to specific positions?

The specific case I had was rotating a game board stored as an int[9]
`[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` becomes `[6,3,0,7,4,1,8,5,2]`

---

In my use case I had a vector of these arrays, which each needed rotating.

Board Layout:

```
board1|corners|centers
0 1 2 | 0   2 |   1  
3 4 5 |       | 3   5
6 7 8 | 6   8 |   7

board2|corners|centers
6 3 0 | 6   0 |   3
7 4 1 |       | 7   1
8 5 2 | 8   2 |   5
```

The fastest method I came up with was to create a public variable to assign the array entries to, and then copy the memory back.

```
int layout[9];
int pub_layout[9];

#include <cstring> // for std::memcpy
void rotate(int layout[])
{
    pub_layout[4] = layout[4]; // center

    pub_layout[0] = layout[6]; // corner four
    pub_layout[6] = layout[8];
    pub_layout[8] = layout[2];
    pub_layout[2] = layout[0];

    pub_layout[1] = layout[3]; // center four
    pub_layout[3] = layout[7];
    pub_layout[7] = layout[5];
    pub_layout[5] = layout[1];

    std::memcpy(layout,pub_layout,sizeof(pub_layout));
}
```

I have seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214292/), which recommends
`int[] b = new int[] {b[6], b[3], b[0], b[7], b[4], b[1], b[8], b[5], b[2]};`
..though it clocks much slower (less than half the speed on a single thread)

---

Both are relatively fast ([see a test here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f511ee17a86c998))

If this is not the fastest method, what is?
I suspect the algorithm will be the same in both C and C++.

Comment: I see a couple of issues with the test code you posted. The `rotate2()` function involves dynamic memory allocations (which all leak in that sample code, btw) while `rotate()` does not. So, it is not surprising that `rotate2()` is slower.  [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc6b9bc5ecfd42ce) is a slightly modified code that uses C++11 containers and algorithms. In this case, `rotate()` and `rotate2()` are comparable and do not involve any dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: have you considered _not_ storing them in row order?  If you stored them in order `0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 6, 3, 4` and used `char` instead of `int` then rotating the board just requires a 3 element shift of the first 8 elements leaving the last element (position 4) invariant.

Comment: further more, with those 8 elements stored in a single `long` the rotation could be achieved with two 24-bit shift operations and a little bit of bit masking.

Comment: Slightly more cleaned up version of the example from my previous comment is available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6363c07428f9cff).

Comment: Algorithms are independent of the language they are implemented in, so your suspicion is wrong. That said, the fastest way is to not rotate them but to offset access accordingly.

Comment: The question is not specifically about rotating small sections of an array, that's just an example of where it could be used. Of course in the general case designing one's algorithm to read references in the desired order would be faster, but that's not the question. This could, for example, be useful to pre-process arrays for another application if they fail a test.

Answer (score 4):

With this one you gain the memcpy call and the [4] to [4] assignment. You lose two assignments to the `putAside` variable. So it is surely a little bit faster.

```
int layout[9];
int putAside;

void rotate(int[] layout)
{
    putAside = layout[0];
    layout[0] = layout[6]; // corner four
    layout[6] = layout[8];
    layout[8] = layout[2];
    layout[2] = putAside;

    putAside = layout[1];
    layout[1] = layout[3]; // center four
    layout[3] = layout[7];
    layout[7] = layout[5];
    layout[5] = putAside;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but the only way to be sure it (or any other approach) is faster would be to do measurements.   But this is the cleanest approach - and one that a compiler has a fair opportunity to optimise like crazy.   May also wish to make `putAside` a local (auto) variable, as there is little value in making it a static.   Note also that you've replicated the mistake of the OP - the type `int [] layout` is not a valid type for a function parameter.

Comment: That is much faster (2.6x) with -O3 on my system and a little faster (14%) when compiled without the flag!  @Peter's suggestion is again a little faster with -O3 (9%) and a little slower without (5%) compared to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is probably to use the processor cache in a very tight loop:

```
void rotate(int in[3][3], int out[3][3])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0,k=2;i<3;i++,k--)
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
            out[j][k] = in[i][j];
}
```

Note: `board[9]` is equivalent to `board[3][3]` and views the 9 ints as 3 sequences of 3 ints contiguous in memory, so if you like:

```
void rotate(int in[9], int out[9])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0,k=2;i<3;i++,k--)
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
            out[j*3+k] = in[i*3+j];
}
```

Should it be required that `in` and `out` can be the same, then you should use the following:

```
void rotate(int in[9], int out[9])
{
    int tmp[9];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i=0,k=2;i<3;i++,k--)
        for (j=0;j<3;j++)
            tmp[j*3+k] = in[i*3+j];
    //memcpy(out,tmp, sizeof(tmp));  // use this...
    for(i=0;i<9;i++) out[i]=tmp[i];  //..or this, whichever clocks faster
}
```

Comment: The problem with your second version of `rotate()` is that it accepts arguments of different type to the first.   So, for the caller, it is not quite a drop in replacement - a type conversion would be necessary to force the compiler to accept it.

Comment: @Peter, I am just giving a different version to match the OPs starting point, which uses an `int[9]` as board. Up to him which one he wants to use.

Comment: This is very fast with -O3 (12% faster than Peter's modification to Joël's on my system), but unfortunately `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` becomes `0 1 6 3 4 3 6 3 6` when it is passed the same parameter `rotate(a,a);`

Comment: @ti7, yes, my algorithm assumes that `in` and `out` are distinct.

Comment: @ti7, fixed that `in` and `out` can be the same at the expense of a copy operation. P.s.: if it is faster, then kindly give an upvote

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more flexible way to apply any transformation, something like the following will also be quite fast:

```
template <int _1, int _2, int _3, int _4, int _5, int _6, int _7, int _8, int _9>
struct transfomer {
    board& _in;
    operator board() const {
      return { _in[_1], _in[_2], _in[_3], _in[_4], _in[_5], _in[_6], _in[_7], _in[_8], _in[_9] };
    }
};

void rotate3(board& layout) {
  layout = transfomer<6, 3, 0, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 2>{layout};
}
```

Here I've defined `board` as:

```
typedef array<int, 9> board;
```

And yes, it relies on the implicit conversion operator (which is normally evil IMO, but is useful here.) (NOTE: I adapted your test a little bit to work with the `array<>` and running the same test shows that the above code is about the same if not slightly better on average than the handrolled solution from @Joel)